# Dropdown is not saved by SubmitForm in PowerApps

Tags: submit, powerapps

I have a dropdownlist filled from sharepoint list, the control is working fine show the items and allow select item, but when I execute the SubmitForm(FrmXXXX) all fields are saved but not the dropdownlists,

Comment: Hello, 

Are the dropdowns in a datacard of your form ?

Comment: Yes, I could solved the problem adding { Value : DataCardValue.Selected.FieldXXXX } in Update properties of Datacard